# What is the best way to make arrows in circular shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, diagram

I need to make (actually re-creating) a diagram for a repeating process consisting of 5 steps.

Here's how it might look with two arrows:

[image]

I need to do basically the same thing with 5 arrows, different colors, and the arrowheads not sticking out... essentially a donut shape.

The arrows also contain text, but that's not a big deal since I can flatten each arrow if the solution involves handling them as separate objects.

I've already tried making the arrows in a straight line and making an art brush, but AI gives me an error saying "The selected artwork contains an element that cannot be made into an art brush." ??? I removed the text just to make sure that wasn't it, but the error still happened.

I also tried making a donut from 2 circles, making compound path, and using the knife to divide into sections... made a nightmare mess out of that. It's nearly impossible to cut a straight line that isn't exactly horizontal, perpendicular, or the exact in between of those.

It looks so simple! Am I just being obtuse? :p

Answer (score 20):

The easiest method is to simply use strokes with arrowheads.

[image: arrows]

for 5 arrows, you simply divide a circle into 5 sections, apply your stroke and arrowheads, then expand and use the **Shape Builder Tool**.

[image: 5 arrows]

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I would do it. I am using a very basic arrow shape. It can be adapted to a more refined  design.

- Step 1: Draw the doughnut with one of the arrows in place. (Here drawn with no fill so the next steps are easy to understand.)

[image]

- Step 2: Select both shapes and make a symbol (drag to symbol panel)
- Step 3: With the symbol selected in the canvas, select Object->Transform->Rotate
- Step 4: Enter 72 degrees (= 360 degrees / 5 slices). For a different number of slices, enter 360 / number of slices
  [image]

  - Step 5: Click on the "Copy" button (as opposed to OK). A new symbol is created.
    [image]
  - Step 6: Repeat step 3, 4 and 5 to created the rest of the slices (3 more times in this case, 4 in total; 1 original slice + 4 slices = 5 slices

[image]

- Step 7: Select the group of slices and expand them together. Object->Expand. The link to the symbol is broken and they are turned into basic shapes.

[image]

- Step 8: With all the shapes selected, use the Pathfinder and click on Divide. This removes redundant overlapping areas.
- Step 9: Double click on the group. Colour each individual shape a different colour.

[image]