# Preparing icon with arrow heads with different sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

I am new to Photoshop, please go easy if my question is unclear. I am trying to prepare an icon in Photoshop and I happened to see [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/22186/17887). So I want a similar graphic but I want the each color area to be sightly smaller than the previous one (i.e., the outer line should be the circle as a whole but the inner side these should be slightly small from the previous one). I want to make the colors look more shiny (gradient) and icon itself look somewhat elevated (not like flat).

So far I did it spending one day like below. But it was not at all fruitful. Though I could reach somewhat what I wanted, the overall shape is not good. When I integrated in the mobile app, it looks very ugly with poor clarity. :(

To try creating this, I have drawn a circle with blue color, and later on copied the layer and decreased the new layer's circle a bit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and filled it with green color and so on, later deleting the unwanted areas with pen tool. As you can see, the circles I have drawn are bent and blurry.

[image: my attempt]

Comment: It's certainly possible in Photoshop, but Illustrator is the appropriate tool for this

Answer (score 1):

Ok as mentioned ideally you would be doing this in Illustrator. But, as that is not the case here is what I would consider quite a simple way of achieving the result you want.

- First select the Ellipse Tool within the Shape Tool menu **Ctrl + U** make sure you have the right shape selected as there are several options.

-Hold **shift** while using the Ellipse too to make a circle as shown at 1 in the image.

-Repeat the above action to make a larger circle,and place it behind the first circle as shown at 2.

-As you can see this gives a sort of template to the type of circle that you were mentioning in your question. Select the smaller circle with the magic wand tool **W** Then select the layer for your larger circle. **Right click** and rasterize this layer, then while it is still selected hit the **backspace** button to clear the selection. You can also hide your smaller circle. This should give the ring shape that you have wanted. As seen at 3.

-To get the points that you want select the Custom Shape Tool, scroll through the shape options and select the triangle. Shown at 4.

- Place and size the triangles around the circle (of course this will be to your own preference, I place 6 for sample sake. (see 5)

You can now use this guide to select the appropriate areas and colour them as you like. I suggest doing this as a layer over the guide that you have created. Once you have that part completed you can then apply a Gradient Overlay to create the shine that you wanted. This can be done by selecting the layer, clicking on *fx* at the bottom of the layers panel. Select 'Gradient Overlay' and toggle your preferences or make a [custom gradient](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1588846&seqNum=23).

As for making it seem somewhat elevated, you could apply a [drop shadow](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/tools/photoshop-drop-shadows/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have any trouble with drop shadow,a shadow effect is better achieved by copying any given layer filling it with black, putting it behind the layer and then moving it a tad to achieve the shadow. Play around with the opacity of the shadow layer to get a better result.
As for making the exact vector is easy as long as you have a bit of practice with shapes and masks.